# Android SDK's some renistalls and the death of Appcelerator Studio

Tags: appcelerator

**NOTE: Thread has been narrowed down to this issue:
[Android SDK's on Appcelerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35022665/android-sdks-on-appcelerator-please-help-me)**

I have been using Titanium since the very beginning and love the product. I have had a bit of a holiday from app development and now have some work to do but I have come across an issue which I just cant resolve).

I use to use Genymotion and TiShadow via the command line and that worked fine. However when I started my long absent journey it was post all the platform changes so I downloaded the Studio and everything seemed fine. However for some bizzare reason running apps from the CLI

```
"ti build -p android --device-id "Xperia" --shadow"
```

Stopped working ( iOS was fine ) so I carried on with my iOS work and then came back to Android later on. So 3 days later I am in a bit of a pickle as I appeared to have bricked my entire installation of Appcelerator ( probably 5 times over ) trying to find the issue.

So after Android not launching from either CLI or Studio it appeared it was hanging whilst running a ti build -p android - adb seemed to be fine and recognised connected devices when Genymotion was open. However I thought I will reinstall the SDK's and Studio again and see what happens. So all installed correctly however when I clicked on "Download" Android button in Studio to configure the SDK's I could select the ones I would require and then it would download them ( taking some time ) only to inform me that the update had failed or it could not find a current version, when I launched Studio again it hung and would just not load.

So after a couple more reinstalls of node, appcelerator, android SDk's I am in the same boat only now I cant even configure Android SDK's it hangs when I click settings.

I realise there is quite a lot a possibilites for this going wrong but I'm stuggling to find out where to start to diagnose the issue.

My main issue now is the I cant even build for iOS on the simulator as I get this error from the CLI.

`/Users/clarkstudios/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/hooks/tisdk3fixes.js:160
            var pd = data.result[1].options['project-dir'],
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
    at cli.on.post (/Users/clarkstudios/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/hooks/tisdk3fixes.js:160:27)
    at /Users/clarkstudios/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/lib/hook.js:242:13
    at /Users/clarkstudios/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:689:13
    at iterate (/Users/clarkstudios/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:265:13)
    at async.forEachOfSeries.async.eachOfSeries (/Users/clarkstudios/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:284:9)
    at _parallel (/Users/clarkstudios/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:688:9)
    at Object.async.series (/Users/clarkstudios/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:710:9)
    at next (/Users/clarkstudios/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/lib/hook.js:232:11)
    at /Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.0.GA/cli/commands/build.js:28:5
    at /Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.0.GA/node_modules/titanium-sdk/lib/titanium.js:116:3
    at Object.exports.execFile (child_process.js:821:9)
    at exports.exec (child_process.js:649:18)
    at async.series.cached (/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/lib/android.js:81:4)
    at /Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:486:21
    at /Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:185:13
    at iterate (/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:108:13)
    at /Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:119:25
    at /Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:187:17
    at /Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:491:34
    at Object.exports.execFile (child_process.js:821:9)
    at exports.exec (child_process.js:649:18)
    at /Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/lib/android.js:68:4
    at /Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:486:21
    at /Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:185:13
    at iterate (/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:108:13)
    at /Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:119:25
    at /Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:187:17
    at /Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.0.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:491:34
    at Object.run (/Users/clarkstudios/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:59:8)
    at find (/Users/clarkstudios/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:96:14)
    at /Users/clarkstudios/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:945:13
    at Immediate.q.process (/Users/clarkstudios/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:913:25)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:367:17)
    at Object.setImmediate (/Users/clarkstudios/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:200:9)
    at _insert (/Users/clarkstudios/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:861:19)
    at Object.q.push (/Users/clarkstudios/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:888:17)
    at Object.findExecutable (/Users/clarkstudios/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:113:8)
    at resolveNode (/Users/clarkstudios/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/lib/titanium.js:97:34)
    at /Users/clarkstudios/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/lib/titanium.js:74:5
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/clarkstudios/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/node_modules/titanium/lib/titanium.js:80:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)`

appc info just hangs as well. I can see another reinstall is imminent but getting to the point where I kind of have no idea what I am doing.

Any help would be great.

Comment: So I have managed to reinstall and get iOS working fine. Android seems to be running but is trying to load an emulator instance that is no longer relevenat which I think is down to the Meta Data. However my big problem is I cannot import any projects to Appcelerator studio as it just crashes - This should not be this difficult.

Comment: Back to Square One!!!!! -- Cannot get Android to work full stop! Ive deleted all my instances of SDK's and cannot get Appcelerator to talk to Android SDK's - When I try to download via Studio it just hangs. When I download from Google and install via Package Manager it does not recognise them. Ive reinstalled over 10 times now - Ive kind of lost the will to even do this as Ive lost 4 days trying to get this to work.

Comment: Even `appc info` from the CLI just hangs so i cant even check out the environment - Diagnostics does nothing in Studio.

Comment: Ive moved on from this and identified the main issue -- New thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35022665/android-sdks-on-appcelerator-please-help-me

Answer (score 0):

First check your Android SDK configuration in Appcelerator studio, Go to

1. studio/preferance/studio/platform/Android check if your SDK path is configured in Android SDK home. Also, as you have Genymotion installed, run the "appc ti config genymotion.enabled true" and check if the Genymotion path is configured in there. If not. update the paths to the executables as needed. Reference http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Installing_Genymotion

Now, Check if your SDK is Fully updated on not, Go to,

2. Android SDK folder/tools/android which will open Android SDK manager and check if it tells you to update and component. Update and install.
3. Now In Genymotion check the devices you have, if you followed the above steps, the studio should show the Genymotion emulators.
4. Try using Titanium SDK 5.1.2.GA with CLI 5.1.0.