# Android SDK's on Appcelerator

Tags: android, appcelerator, genymotion

I used to have a full working system with Genymotion and tishadow.

I have

- Reinstalled Studio numerous times
- Reinstalled Appcelerator numerous times
- Removed all SDK's from Appcelerator
- Installed Android Developer SDK's numerous times

I think I have gone through every permutation and still no working development environment. I prefer to use CLI with ST2 rather than Studio as I find it clunky and just a bit heavy of node calls with regular MacOSX beach ball attacks on my screen.

So my main issue still lies with the SDK's. I managed to get a full list of emulators installed and Appcelerator pointing to what would appear to be the right place. See the image below:

[image: Appcelerator Studio Android SDKs]

I am on the right track no more crashes or hang ups trying to point to the directory. So next step for me was to install Genymotion set up an emulator and then get it to appear in Studio - this is where my confusion begins.

Genymotion installed and emulator set up and titanium config for GenyMotion set to true. No crashes. As I did this my emulators in Studio appeared to just disappear.

[image: Where are my emulators]

So restart of Studio and the emulators now appear again. So my next step is to do a cli build and see what Android emulators are available and to see if we get the same list as on Studio (We should do right as this Studio is just a GUI interface to CLI). Terminal opened, navigate to the directory and then type:

```
`appc ti build -p android`
```

The CLI presents me with a list of emulators:

[image: WTF! Totally different set of emulators]

Now I'm completely confused and this is where I think all my problems are coming from. Now if I try to run Genymotion emulator (Number 7 in this list) it goes through the motions but never launches the emulator. I've read that you need the emulator open already but if I do that then the CLI just hangs on with the build command above and does nothing.

Can anyone offer me some light.

Below are some environment settings from the trace.

```
`Operating System
Name                        = Mac OS X
Version                     = 10.11.2
Architecture                = 64bit
# CPUs                      = 4
Memory                      = 17179869184

Node.js
Node.js Version             = 0.12.7
npm Version                 = 2.11.3

Titanium CLI
CLI Version                 = 5.0.5

Titanium SDK
SDK Version                 = 5.1.2.GA
SDK Path                    = /Users/<MY_USER_HERE>/Library/Application      Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.1.2.GA
Target Platform             = android`
```

Comment: Android builds from the CLI seem to just hang on this: `Emulator exists, detecting all running emulators and connected devices...`

Comment: Running appc `ti info -t android` does nothing I just get a spinning cursor in Terminal.

Comment: I'm now trying to Refresh Devices in Studio as the ones that appear in the CLI match those in AVD list. Refresh Devices seems to just time out though.

Comment: Reinstalled Ti Studio removed all Android SDK's. Installed Android SDK through Ti Studio ( 5.0 ) then looked at emulators list all the emulators there are as above image but AVD has only 1. CLI shows correct AVD's. Exit Ti Studio, reopen it go to Android SDK's ( to install one more ) and all of them are greyed out from the previous SDK folder I had. Restarted Mac went to Ti Studio again and to Properties > Platforms > Android no default emulator set, click on Manage AVD's Studio hangs, Reopen click on Install More SDK's nothing appears. Painful - Im out of ideas!

Comment: I left the CLI attempting to run a build on an AVD I built ( 1 hour or so ) and got this error appear:  `[ERROR] Unable to start Android Debug Bridge server (exit code Error: Failed to start ADB (code 255): error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Connection reset by peer`

Comment: As I left it last night I had SDK installed in Ti Studio ( I installed it to test if the sdk appeared in there ). I did not shut down my macbook just shut the lid and went to bed. I opened it up this morning and Studio tells me No Android SDK could be found in the current location.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Genymotion 2.6? This is not supported yet. You can find a simple workaround in the comments on the related ticket:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20130

Comment: Hi Fokke, thanks for the answer. I have tried both workarounds as explained in the ticket. If I open the target emulator in Genymotion then the CLI fails to move past the welcome screen and opens about 11 node processes, it seems to be trying to do something but it seems to get stuck. If I don't open the emulator I get a full build log then it hangs attempting to to launch the emulator. I still get Android SDK errors in Ti Studio despite installing them 6 times ( I must admit I dont like using Studio )

Comment: I think this has more to do with my continuing issues with the "No Android SDKs were found under the specified SDK location" I think I have about exhausted every possible fix for this from the web.

Comment: Hi Fokke, again sorry trying to debug my own problem. So I uninstalled everything again this time I didnt bother downloading Studio and installed via the command line. I updated the Google SDK's and finally in `ti setup` I have a discovered Android SDK. I created a new 'stock' AVD rather than use GenyMotion but that has the same issue the app builds but will not launch the emulator. So close now!

Answer (score -2):

You need to configure the Titanium CLI.

```
appc ti config genymotion.enabled true
```

Please check the [link](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Installing+Genymotion#InstallingGenymotion-ConfiguringGenymotion) from more information.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I already have this set in my config. The app builds but I just get:     `[INFO]  Alloy compiler completed successfully
[INFO]  Launching emulator: SG3` nothing happens. Ive tried with Genymotion emulator open and then running     `appc ti build -p android` in this scenario Appcelerator does not even build the app it just hangs.